# The ed text editor and line feed

Tags: unix, text-editors

With `ed` can I add line feeds (\n)?

I've tried:

```
s/word/word\n/
```

But it it just gave me a plain "n" after word. With double backslash appeared "\n".

With `sed` this works as expected, but with `ed` not.

I'm not worried if its going to work or not, I'm just playing around with Unix tools...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ed's man page says "Newlines may be embedded in replacement if they are escaped with a backslash ()." This seems to mean don't write \n, instead write \ then press return.

```
$ echo word > testfile
$ ed testfile
5
s/word/word\
more/
w
q
$ cat testfile
word
more
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what about the sequence \r\n?

Comment: Just to people known, the text "Newlines (...)" you can see with the `info ed` command, in the node "Commands".

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if `\r` was a meaningless concept to ed. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1761086/478656 point 1.

Comment: I notice a comment here: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?EdIsTheStandardTextEditor saying the CP/M version of ed could edit \r and \n separately and they've never found another version that behaves the same, and a reply saying the Unix version never could because it's inherently a line editor, not a character editor -- implying to me that it would only have a "line end" character, i.e. \n in Unix land.